# Push created value inside map into new array to reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function and before the map runs i do calculations to get a discount then take the discount and subtract it from a current price.

This works good in showing the discount and the new price but I need to be able to take all the final prices (Current price - discount) and create a total for the cart.

My thought was I could use a reduce on finalPrice but since its not in an array when it spits out (They push out seperatley) i cant run a reduce function on them to get the total i get told reduce.finalPrice is not a function. How can I push the final prices into one array to reduce?

```js
          {User?.Cart && User?.Cart.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <table className="w-full table-auto">
                <thead>
                  <tr className="text-left border-b-2 border-baileysBlue">
                    <th className="py-5">Product</th>
                    <th className="py-5">Price</th>
                    <th className="py-5">Discount</th>
                    <th className="py-5">Final Price</th>
                    <th className="py-5">Quantity</th>
                    <th className="py-5">Controls</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {User.Cart.map((prod, i) => {
                    let discountPrice = prod.CurrentPrice.toString().endsWith('97') ? parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.05 : parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.15
                    let finalPrice = parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) - parseFloat(discountPrice)
                    console.log(finalPrice)
                    return (
                      <tr
                        key={`key-cart-prod-${i}`}
                        className="border-b border-opacity-50 border-baileysBlue"
                      >
                        <td className="py-5">
                          <Link href={`/product/${prod.Slug}`}>
                            <a>
                              {`${prod.Description} (${prod.ProductID})`}
                            </a>
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td className="py-5">{`${prod.CurrentPrice}`}</td>
                        <td className="py-5">{`${discountPrice}`}</td>
                        <td className="py-5">{`${finalPrice}`}</td>
                        <td className="py-5">{`Qty: ${prod.Quantity}`}</td>
                        <td className="py-5" style={{width: '1%', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>
                          <RemoveFromCart ProductID={prod.ProductID} />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Edit

Try thing but still getting them pushing to seperate arrays

```js
             {User.Cart.map((prod, i) => {
                    let totals = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < prod.Quantity; i++) {
                      let discountPrice = prod.CurrentPrice.toString().endsWith('97') ? parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.05 : parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.15
                      let finalPrice = parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) - parseFloat(discountPrice)
                      totals.push(finalPrice)
                    }
                    console.log('totals', totals)
```

Comment: Aren't you already getting the final price of an **individual** item by currentPrice - discountPrice ? Or do you mean to get the final price of **all** the items ?

Comment: I am looking to get the Total Price of all discounted items (finalPrice)

So for each FinalPrice i get returned i want to add them together to get a total price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the prices in the .map(),

```
let total = 0;

User.Cart.map((prod, i) => {
    let discountPrice = prod.CurrentPrice.toString().endsWith('97') ? 
    parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.05 : parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.15
    let finalPrice = parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) - parseFloat(discountPrice)
    console.log(finalPrice)
    total = total + finalPrice;
    // rest of map function here
});

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate array, and then append `finalPrice` to that array, and then finally use `.reduce()` to sum the array and use it.

```js
let prices = [];

User.Cart.map((prod, i) => {
    let discountPrice = prod.CurrentPrice.toString().endsWith('97') ? 
    parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.05 : parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) * 0.15
    let finalPrice = parseFloat(prod.CurrentPrice) - parseFloat(discountPrice)
    console.log(finalPrice)
    prices.append(finalPrice);
    // rest of map function here
});

let total = prices.reduce((acc, cv) => acc + cv);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modeling problem. You're trying to operate on your original array inside the markup, which can be a bit confusing.

Try to model your data before the JSX on your component by doing

```js
const cart = (User?.Cart || []).map((prod) => {
  const discount = ...
  const finalPrice = prod.currentPrice - discount;

  return {
    ...prod,
    discount,
    finalPrice,
  };
});
```

Then, it's easy to evaluate the total with

```js
const total = cart.reduce((total, prod) => prod.finalPrice, 0);
```

Then, on your JSX, you can use those variables as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it was a modeling problem it felt really messy how i did it, though i continued with my messy method, i plan to refactor to this.